what does ナシ in this context mean?

ビジネスシーンにはどうもセクシー過ぎる気がしないでもないけれど、彼女は経営者であるし個性を重んじる考え方であるのは理解できる。
また慣れというのは恐ろしいもので、年中この姿で一貫されるとそんなにナシとも思わなくなるのが不思議だ。

does ナシ mean なし? if so ,I can't see how it fit in this context.

It's the antonym for アリ. I'm a bit surprised that there doesn't seem to be an answer that explains both アリ and ナシ in a single answer on this site yet...

In this context, ナシ means "unacceptable." The sentence discusses how her outfit might feel too sexy for the business scene, but as she consistently dresses this way, people get used to it, and over time it no longer feels unacceptable.
